# react-native-material-ui uiTheme.spacing error

Tags: react-native

Unknown error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object 
(evaluating
'context.uiTheme.spacing')
```

in my component code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { IconToggle } from 'react-native-material-ui'

export default class LeftElement extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <IconToggle name="menu" color="white" />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

It seems that we should provide a themeProvider.spacing to IconToggle

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { IconToggle, ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-material-ui'

const uiTheme = {
  spacing: {
    fontSize: 24
  }
}
export default class LeftElement extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider uiTheme={uiTheme}>
        <View>
          <IconToggle name="menu" color="white" />
        </View>
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

But it also can not work,
how should I resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Please go through proper guidelines of [react-native-material-ui](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui), Install [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) also link `react-native-vector-icons` to your react-native project.

I have just changed color "black", and it is showing like this below.

```
<ThemeProvider uiTheme={uiTheme}>
   <View>
     <IconToggle name="menu" color="black" />
   </View>
</ThemeProvider>
```

It gives you following output,

[image]

Comment: How did you set your {uiTheme}?